# Uploading an image to my website causes a 500 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried to upload an image in my site and I had made this piece of code that worked very well but now it's going as I planned I tried to modify the url
url: 'ajax/uploadifive.php' in url: './ajax/uploadifive.php' even in url: 'https://www.nanaje.com/ajax/uploadifive.php' but nothing works I don't know why

Here is the Ajax jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL

        var bar = $('.bar')
        var percent = $('.percent')
        var progress_bar_id = '#progress-wrp' //ID of an element for response output
        var url = $('#url').val() // Url of the page gallery of image
        
        var ajaxCall
        
        $('#file').change(function () {
            var file = $(this)[0].files[0]

            img = new Image()
            var imgwidth = 0
            var imgheight = 0
            var minwidth = 640 // Minimum width required W: 640
            var minheight = 320 // Minimum length required H: 320
            
            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file)
            img.onload = function() {
                imgwidth = this.width // Original Image Width
                imgheight = this.height // Original Length Of The Image
                
                if (imgwidth >= minwidth && imgheight >= minheight) {
                    var formData = new FormData()
                    formData.append('fileToUpload', $('#file')[0].files[0])
                    
                    ajaxCall = $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajax/uploadifive.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $('.progress-bar').show()
                            $(progress_bar_id + " .load_file").html('<img src="assets/img/ajax-loader.gif" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"/>')
                            $(progress_bar_id + " .cancel").html('Cancel')
                        },
                        xhr: function(){
                            //upload Progress
                            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr()
                            if (xhr.upload) {
                                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                                    var percent = 0
                                    var position = event.loaded || event.position
                                    var total = event.total
                                    var total_file = Math.round((total / 1024) /1024)
                                    var total_file_kb = Math.round(total / 1024)
                                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                                        percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100)
                                    }
                                    //update progressbar
                                    $(progress_bar_id +" .progress-bar").attr("value", percent)
                                    $(progress_bar_id + " .status").text(percent +"%")
                                    $(progress_bar_id + " .status_from").text("from")
                                    if(total_file != 0) {
                                        $(progress_bar_id + " .status_total").text(total_file+'Mb')
                                    } else {
                                        $(progress_bar_id + " .status_total").text(total_file_kb+'Kb')
                                    }
                                }, true)
                            }
                            return xhr
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            if(response.status == 1) {
                                $(progress_bar_id + " .load_file").hide()
                                $(progress_bar_id + " .cancel").hide()
                                window.location = url
                            } else {
                                $(progress_bar_id + " .load_file").hide()
                                $(progress_bar_id + " .cancel").text('Failed')
                                swal({
                                  text: response.returnText,
                                  icon: "info",
                                })
                                return false
                            } 
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    swal({
                      text: "Dezole, imaj sa a twò piti oswa twò gwo kalite, tanpri eseye ankò ak yon lòt imaj ki gen pi bon kalite. Nou sijere ke ou soumèt vèsyon orijinal la, kote ou fe li ak pwòp telefon ou, ki pat janm te redwi oswa chanje.",
                      icon: "info",
                    })
                    return false
                }
            }
            img.onerror = function() {
                $("#response").text("fichier a pa bon " + file.type)
            }
        })
        
        $(document).on('click','.cancel', function() {
            ajaxCall.abort()
            $(progress_bar_id + " .load_file").hide()
            $(progress_bar_id + " .cancel").text('Failed')
        })
    })
</script>
```

and here is the php code

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../class/Database.php';
require_once '../includes/functions.php';
require_once '../includes/constants.php';
require_once '../src/interventionImage/autoload.php';

use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;

// We create the instance so that we can use the image
$manager = new ImageManager();
/*
UploadiFive
Copyright (c) 2012 applications réactives, Ronnie Garcia
*/
$returnText = "";
$uploadOk = 1;
// Set the download directory
// We define the user's Id
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$dir_img = '../photos/m/'.$id.'/i';
$uploadDir = "$dir_img/oi"; // Place of destination of the original image
// $uploadDirProfile = "$dir_img/oip"; // Place of destination of the original image
$uploadDirImgHomeProfile = "$dir_img/ihp"; // Place of destination of the img_home_profile
$uploadDirAvatar = "$dir_img/ai"; // Place of destination of the avatar image
$uploadDirImgProfileExtra = "$dir_img/ipe"; // Place of destination of the avatar image
$uploadDirImgGallery = "$dir_img/ig"; // Place of destination of the avatar image
$uploadDirImgMessage = "$dir_img/im"; // Place of destination of the avatar image
$uploadDirStandardProfile = "$dir_img/sp"; // Place of destination of the avatar image

// Let's test the fioxtension
$nomFichier = pathinfo($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']); //nom complet de l'image avec son extension
$nameFile = $nomFichier['basename']; //nom complet de l'image avec son extension
$extension_file = $nomFichier['extension']; // L'extension de l'image

$field = 'nfo';
$value = $nameFile;
$table = 'pictures';

if(is_already_in_use($field, $value, $table)) {
    $returnText = "You have already put this image on the site.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
} else {
    // Define allowed file extensions
    $fileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg']; // Allowed file extensions

    $verifyToken = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $targetPath = $uploadDir; // Place or store the image on the site server
    // $targetPathProfile = $uploadDirProfile; // Place or store the image on the site server
    $targetPathImgHomeProfile = $uploadDirImgHomeProfile; // Place or store the image on the site server 
    $targetPathAvatar = $uploadDirAvatar; // Place or store the image on the site server
    $targetPathImgProfileExtra = $uploadDirImgProfileExtra; // Place or store the image on the site server
    $targetPathImgGallery = $uploadDirImgGallery; // Place or store the image on the site server
    $targetPathImgMessage = $uploadDirImgMessage; // Place or store the image on the site server
    $targetPathStandardProfile = $uploadDirStandardProfile; // Place or store the image on the site server
    $randomFileName = $verifyToken.'.'.$extension_file;

    if (!empty($_FILES) && $verifyToken) {

        $tempFile = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
        $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $randomFileName; // The place where the image will be stored

        if(!file_exists($targetPath)) {
            mkdir("$dir_img/oi", 0755, true);
        }
        
        if (in_array(strtolower($extension_file), $fileTypes)) {

            // We take the current image...
            $tempFileOriginal = $manager->make($tempFile);

            // Img Logo
            // $img_logo = $manager->make(WEBSITE_NAME_URL.'/assets/img/Logopit_1571868283797.png')->resize(700, 400); // 700X400 300X300

            $tempFileOriginal->orientate()->text('nanaje.com', 720, 1000, function($font) {
                $font->file('../assets/img/Texturina-Italic-VariableFont_opsz,wght.ttf');
                $font->size(48);
                $font->color('#be0210');
            })->interlace(true)->save($targetFile, 60);

            // $tempFileOriginal->orientate()->insert($img_logo, 'bottom-right', -10, -100)->interlace(true)->save($targetFile, 60);

            // save the file, ie the original image
            if ($tempFileOriginal) {
                
                $filename = $targetFile;

                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filename);

                if ($width < 640 && $height < 320) {
                    unlink($filename);
                    $returnText = "Sorry, this image is too small or of too low a quality, please try again with another image of better quality. We suggest that you submit the original version of your recent photo that has never been reduced or altered.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }

                if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                    $returnText;
                } else {
                    /**
                     * Create the targetPathProfile for your profile for modal box
                     */
                        // We save the modal box resize image in the file
                        $thumbnailPathProfile = rtrim($targetPathProfile,'/') . '/' . $randomFileName; // The place where the image will be stored
                        
                        // We check if this path exists, if not, we create it
                        if (!file_exists($thumbnailPathProfile)) {
                            mkdir("$targetPathProfile", 0755, true);
                        } 

                        $width = 900; // Maximum width
                        $height = 900; // Maximum height

                        // We take the current image...
                        $img = $manager->make($targetFile);

                        // We check which height or width we should keep...  
                        ($img->height() > $img->width()) ? $width = null : $height = null;

                        $img->orientate()->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
                            $constraint->aspectRatio();
                        })->interlace(true)->save($thumbnailPathProfile, 60); //900x900
                    /** END */
                    
                    
                    /**
                     * Create the img_home_profile
                     */
                        // We save the AVATAR resize image in the file
                        $thumbnailPathImgHomeProfile = rtrim($targetPathImgHomeProfile,'/') . '/' . $randomFileName; // The place where the image will be stored
                        
                        // We check if this path exists, if not, we create it
                        if (!file_exists($thumbnailPathImgHomeProfile)) {
                            mkdir("$targetPathImgHomeProfile", 0755, true);
                        } 

                        $width = 218; // Maximum width
                        $height = 218; // Maximum height

                        // We take the current image...
                        $img = $manager->make($targetFile);

                        // Img Logo
                        // $img_logo = $manager->make(WEBSITE_NAME_URL.'/assets/img/Logopit_1571868283797.png')->resize(700, 400); // 700X400

                        // $img->orientate()->insert($img_logo, 'bottom-right', -10, -100)->resize($width, $height)->interlace(true)->save($thumbnailPathImgHomeProfile, 60); /90089008
                        $img->orientate()->resize($width, $height)->interlace(true)->save($thumbnailPathImgHomeProfile, 60); //218x218
                    /** END */

                    /**
                     * Create the Avatar Profile
                     */
                        // We save the AVATAR resize image in the file
                        $thumbnailPathAvatar = rtrim($targetPathAvatar,'/') . '/' . $randomFileName; // The place where the image will be stored
                        
                        // We check if this path exists, if not, we create it
                        if (!file_exists($thumbnailPathAvatar)) {
                            mkdir("$targetPathAvatar", 0755, true);
                        } 

                        $width = 500; // Maximum width
                        $height = 500; // Maximum height
                        
                        // We take the current image...
                        $img = $manager->make($targetFile);

                        // Img Logo
                        // $img_logo = $manager->make(WEBSITE_NAME_URL.'/assets/img/Logopit_1571868283797.png')->resize(700, 400); // 700X400
                        
                        // We check which height or width we should keep...  
                        ($img->height() > $img->width()) ? $width = null : $height = null;

                        // $img->orientate()->insert($img_logo, 'bottom-right', -10, -100)->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
                        $img->orientate()->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
                            $constraint->aspectRatio();
                        })->interlace(true)->save($thumbnailPathAvatar, 60); //500x500
                    /** END */

                    /**
                     * Create the Avatar Profile Extra
                     */
                        // We save the AVATAR resize image in the file
                        $thumbnailPathImgProfileExtra = rtrim($targetPathImgProfileExtra,'/') . '/' . $randomFileName; // The place where the image will be stored
                        
                        // We check if this path exists, if not, we create it
                        if (!file_exists($thumbnailPathImgProfileExtra)) {
                            mkdir("$targetPathImgProfileExtra", 0755, true);
                        }

                        $width = 80; // Maximum width
                        $height = 80; // Maximum height

                        // We take the current image...
                        $img = $manager->make($targetFile);

                        $img->orientate()->fit($width, $height)->interlace(true)->save($thumbnailPathImgProfileExtra, 60); //80x80
                    /** END */

                    /**
                     * Create the Avatar Profile Gallery
                     */
                        // We save the AVATAR resize image in the file
                        $thumbnailPathImgGallery = rtrim($targetPathImgGallery,'/') . '/' . $randomFileName; // The place where the image will be stored

                        // We check if this path exists, if not, we create it
                        if (!file_exists($thumbnailPathImgGallery)) {
                            mkdir("$targetPathImgGallery", 0755, true);
                        }

                        $width = 190; // Maximum width
                        $height = 190; // Maximum height

                        // We take the current image...
                        $img = $manager->make($targetFile);

                        // Img Logo
                        // $img_logo = $manager->make(WEBSITE_NAME_URL.'/assets/img/Logopit_1571868283797.png')->resize(700, 400); // 700X400

                        // $img->orientate()->insert($img_logo, 'bottom-right', -10, -100)->resize($width, $height)->interlace(true)->save($thumbnailPathImgGallery, 60); //80x80
                        $img->orientate()->resize($width, $height)->interlace(true)->save($thumbnailPathImgGallery, 60); //80x80
                    /** END */

                    /**
                     * Create the Avatar Profile Message
                     */
                        // We save the AVATAR resize image in the file
                        $thumbnailPathImgMessage = rtrim($targetPathImgMessage,'/') . '/' . $randomFileName; // The place where the image will be stored

                        // We check if this path exists, if not, we create it
                        if (!file_exists($thumbnailPathImgMessage)) {
                            mkdir("$targetPathImgMessage", 0755, true);
                        }

                        $width = 32; // Maximum width
                        $height = 32; // Maximum height

                        // We take the current image...
                        $img = $manager->make($targetFile);

                        // $img->orientate()->fit($width, $height)->interlace(true)->save($thumbnailPathImgMessage, 60); //32x32
                        $img->orientate()->fit($width, $height)->interlace(true)->save($thumbnailPathImgMessage, 60); //32x32
                    /** END */

                    /**
                     * Create the img_home_profile standard_home
                     */

                    // We save the AVATAR resize image in the file
                    $thumbnailPathStandardProfile = rtrim($targetPathStandardProfile,'/') . '/' . $randomFileName; // The place where the image will be stored
                    
                    // We check if this path exists, if not, we create it
                    if (!file_exists($thumbnailPathStandardProfile)) {
                        mkdir("$targetPathStandardProfile", 0755, true);
                    }

                    $width = 320; // Maximum width
                    $height = 240; // Maximum height

                    // We take the current image...
                    $img = $manager->make($targetFile);

                    // Img Logo
                    // $img_logo = $manager->make(WEBSITE_NAME_URL.'/assets/img/Logopit_1571868283797.png')->resize(700, 400); // 700X400

                    $img->orientate()->fit($width, $height)->interlace(true)->save($thumbnailPathStandardProfile, 60); //32x32

                    /** END */

                    unlink($filename);
                    
                    $q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO pictures(io, nfo, ihp, ai, ipe, ig, im, sp, rules, picture_added, ip, user_id)
                                       VALUES(:io, :nfo, :ihp, :ai, :ipe, :ig, :im, :sp, :rules, now(), :ip, :user_id)");
                    $q->execute([ 
                        'io' => $thumbnailPathProfile, 
                        'nfo' => $nameFile, 
                        'ihp' => $thumbnailPathImgHomeProfile,
                        'ai' => $thumbnailPathAvatar,
                        'ipe' => $thumbnailPathImgProfileExtra,
                        'ig' => $thumbnailPathImgGallery,
                        'im' => $thumbnailPathImgMessage,
                        'sp' => $thumbnailPathStandardProfile,
                        'rules' => '1',
                        'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                        'user_id' => $id
                    ]);
                    
                    $picture_user_id = $db->lastInsertId();

                    if ($picture_user_id) {

                        $q = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM pictures WHERE user_id = ? AND active_profile = ?");
                        $q->execute([get_session('user_id'), '2']);

                        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                        if (!$data) {
                            $q = $db->prepare("UPDATE pictures SET active_profile = ? WHERE id = ?");
                            $q->execute(['2', $picture_user_id]);
                        }
                        // End of the backup
                        
                        $q = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM notes_picture_personal WHERE user_id = ?");
                        $q->execute([$id]);

                        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                        // If this is the case we continue ...
                        if ($data) {
                            // Then we update the field of the database of the user ...
                            $q = $db->prepare("UPDATE notes_picture_personal SET notes_picture_perso = notes_picture_perso + 1 WHERE user_id = ?");
                            $q->execute([$id]);
                        } else {
                            // Write the number of fields that have inserted...
                            $q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO notes_picture_personal(user_id, notes_picture_perso) VALUES(?, ?)");
                            $q->execute([$id, 1]);
                            // End of the backup
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $returnText = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        } else {
            $returnText = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            $returnText;
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode(array("status"=>$uploadOk,"returnText"=>$returnText));
?>
```

and here are the images of the error that is displayed
[POST https://www.nanaje.com/ajax/uploadifive.php 500 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDAOD.jpg)

POST https://www.nanaje.com/ajax/uploadifive.php 500 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:

Comment: You need to check your server's logs. In them will be details about the 500 error.

Comment: You could try checking folder permissions.